# how to make wpfapp always on top and not blocked by taskbar

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, button, desktop

I used a wpf and set Topmost=true, this works for other applications but I want to put the form in taskbar, when the task bar get focus, the form is blocked.
I want to know if there is any method to make the form always on top?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gqyap.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K5aM2.png)
Another question is that I want to add some buttons on taskbar so that I can click them easily, but I only found trayIcon which is limited in functions.

Comment: Please don't put multiple question in one post. Also, I suggest you to make a [mre] to make it easier to help you !

Answer (score 0):

```
YourCustomWindow cw = new YourCustomWindow ();

cw.Owner = Application.Current.MainWindow;

cw.ShowInTaskbar = false;

cw.ShowDialog() ;
```